# Get selected Datagridview (rows) to database

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working with a new project and I do not know where I am messing up. I hoped a few new pairs of eye might be able to help me out and guide me in the right direction.

My Windows Form has a datagridview and a button, the button is to save the selected rows that the user selects and save them to database. I am not concerned with the saving at the moment I would like to know where I am doing wrong with the `dataGridView.Selected.Rows`? I have changed the SelectionMode property of the datagridview to "full row select". When it gets to foreach loop the selected rows are broke up and saved to the designated object and then the whole object is saved to the tabel/database. When it gets to saving it it seems to have all of the rows from the datagridview not only the user selected ones...

Thanks in advance

```
   foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
        {

            int i = 0;
            i = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index;

            log slog = new log();

            slog.Date = dataGridView1[0, i].Value.ToString();
            slog.Level = dataGridView1[1, i].Value.ToString();
            slog.Project = dataGridView1[2, i].Value.ToString();
            slog.Number = dataGridView1[3, i].Value.ToString();
            slog.Method = dataGridView1[4, i].Value.ToString();
            slog.Property = dataGridView1[5, i].Value.ToString();

            logEntity.logs.AddObject(slog);

        }
   logEntity.SaveChanges();
}
```

-

```
//other code tried
//for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count - 1; i++)
//var rowIndexes = dataGridView1.SelectedCells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>()
//          .Select(cell => cell.RowIndex)
//          .Distinct();
//dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Select(r => r.Index);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is with the indexing.  I would get rid if `i` since you already have the row you want.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
        {
         log slog = new log();

         slog.Date = dr.cells(0).Value.ToString();
         slog.Level = dr.cells(1).Value.ToString();
         slog.Project = dr.cells(2).Value.ToString();
         slog.Number = dr.cells(3).Value.ToString();
         slog.Method = dr.cells(4).Value.ToString();
         slog.Property = dr.cells(5).Value.ToString();

         logEntity.logs.AddObject(slog);

        }
logEntity.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks I am sure it seemed so simple to anyone else but after staring at this issue for the past 3 days I was getting annoyed. It is selecting the selected rows as is should. Thanks again!